# Login with basic authentication not working

Tags: asp.net-web-api, basic-authentication

I try to login my web service but chrome asking username and password again and again.(username and password true)It's work on Firefox.

Solved.

Solution:I disabled Windows Authentication from IIS

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! Please read [How to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to see how to ask a good question. Without seeing your code and more details it's difficult to know how to help.

Comment: If you are new to SO I would recommend reading https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Hi, take a look at the following article which explains in detail what it going on. Hopefully this will fix your issue ;)    regards Craig